# Text Caption not shared on facebook

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share photo with caption but text caption is not shared on Facebook Is there any way to share a text with photo on Facebook using send intent.

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Virtual Mirror Photo");
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This photo is created by Virtual Mirror App.\n\nInfoshore Team");
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
            targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            isAppAvaiable = true;
        }
    }
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Facebook's Platform Policies, you cannot pre-fill the share dialog using
`Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. It is usually thought to be a bug, but as per a Bug Report filed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) and also, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/363863587019268), Facebook clearly mentions that this is not the case (it's not a bug).

You can read more about their [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) specifically, **Platform Policy IV.2**

*Quote from Platform Policy IV.2:*

> You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following
>   products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in
>   the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for
>   Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message
>   parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description),
>   Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.
>
> These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling
>   these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice.

The bottom line is (unfortunately), you cannot add a caption to a photo you are uploading using `Intents`. The only way you can do it, is integrating the Facebook SDK in your App. To see an example of how they do it in their sample app *Hackbook*, refer to  [this link](https://github.com/imkevinxu/totoro/blob/master/facebook-android-sdk-3.0/samples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Hackbook.java)  and scroll down to line **263** where they deal with uploading a Photo with a Caption.

Comment: The Platform Policies and the Hackbook links are broken.

Comment: @BraisGabin: Fixing the links. Thanks for pointing that out. :-)

Comment: This is a bug, if Facebook doesn't respect the Intent parameters it is a bug - and no policy can cover for it. If they don't want to respect the Intent they shouldn't register for it.  This specific FB bug breaks down the expected behavior of Android intent system.

p.s. the link to Hackbook is broken.

Comment: This is quite sad.  Specifically as this functionality, apparently, exists on iOS version of Facebook app...