# android sharing application

Tags: android, facebook, photo, sharing

I have a few problems with my android app. I want to share some text and photo to fb and twitter. The first problem is that i can't copy the text from my textfield to the fb message ... i mean i have a text field with the text you want to share and 2 buttons ( fb, twitter) and the twitter side is working fine but i can't attach the text to the fb message ( the window appears on the push of the button but it's blank). Here is my code for sharing on facebbok:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    txt.getText());
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    txt.getText());
            PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    shareIntent, 0);
            for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                    final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                    final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                            activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            activity.name);
                    shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

My other problem is that my photo browser is giving me a path of the file like this: "external/images/media/photo" and i though that the problem is that i have to copy the extension too (.jpg etc.) but that's not it. If i use a direct path: "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/01.jpg" it's working fine. Can someone help me how to find the direct path of the photo or how can i modify my code that it works with the first one:

```
private void share(String nameApp, String imagePath, String text) {
    try {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg");
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(
                        nameApp)
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                                nameApp)) {
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
                    targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                    targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Thx anticipated ...

Comment: I believe at this moment facebook does not support `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Because they want you to use their sdk, the same should be with twitter, strange that you made it to work)

Comment: maybe ur wright but the twitter part is working fine with or without photo ... someone told me that i cant share on fb photo and text at the same time only with the facebook sdk so i wanted to make them seperate ... the photo part is working fine with fb too but i can't the text part doesn't ...

Comment: i also wanted to integrate facebook share to my app, and when i saw that they want to use their sdk, i just passed it. Somewhere also was official answer from facebook that they will not put it in their app, so...

Comment: Hi this is the know bug in the facebook.. we cannot pass our string to the status field.. for that may be you have to create own popup(Alert) to share it.

Comment: ok guys thx ... with the photo browsing problem can someone help me?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523569/text-caption-not-shared-on-facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact path of your image as below, I have already shared the photo & text on FB & Twitter the way you have shared and its working fine for me also. Hope this will help you.

**EDITED:**

> ```
>   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>         if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
>             Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
>             selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
>         }
>     }
> }
> public String getPath(Uri uri) {
>     String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
>     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
>     int column_index = cursor
>             .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
>     cursor.moveToFirst();
>     return cursor.getString(column_index);
> }
> ```

Comment: i have to browse a photo from my phone not an exact photo like 01.jpg ... how can i use this to get the exact file path?

Comment: Then you can open the gallery of from the device and get the path of the selected photo of the gallery.

Comment: `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
       path = selectedImage.getPath();
       txt.setText(path);
     } 
 } `

Comment: and this is how i call it:
`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_IMAGE); `

Comment: You should get the path using the code which you have implemented. What exactly problem that you are facing?

Comment: the selectedImage.getPath() is returning : "external/images/media/photo" but this from this path the image can't be loaded ... with something like this : "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/01.jpg" it's working fine but idk why i get a path like the first one ...

Comment: I have edited my code .Just try to change your `getPath()` method to get the image path. I hope it will work

Comment: I m glad to hear that it works. please dnt forget to vote the right answer. Thank you. :)